# Use text file as a source of input

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Okay so basically I want to be able to use a text file with this format:

```
www.website.com 443 123.456.789.098
www.website2.com 443 765.432.101.234
....
```

as a source of input in which the script will take the website address and hold it in a variable and the same thing with the port and Ip address. So it would look like this:

```
website=www.website.com
port=443
ip=123.456.789.098
```

So far, I have tried this:

```
for line in [ cat $file_name ]; do
    website=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f1`
    port=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f2`
    ip=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f1`
```

But when i echo out the the variables all i get is this:

```
[
[
[
```

I can't seem to figure out how to go about solving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this pattern instead:

```
while read line ; do
    ... loop body ...
done < "$file_name"
```

Explanation: `for var in word-list` will assign the words in the list to the variable in order. So for the first loop, `$line` will expand to `[` (first word in the list). The next word would be `cat` and then the value of `file_name`.

To read from a file, you need to use [I/O redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections).

`while`, on the other hand, will execute the command that you passed as argument (`read line`). `read` will read one line from `stdin` and put the value into the variable that you passed as argument.

The odd `done < $file_name` sets the `stdin` for read. And to make you life even more simple, you can use `read` to split the input for you:

```
while read website port id ; do
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`for` does not read line by line by default but reads tokens delimited by $IFS. By default, IFS usually contains space, tab and newline. If you want to force bash to read line by line (and not whitespace separated tokens), you can do so with:

```
IFS=`echo -ne '"\n"'`; for line in `cat $file`; do echo $line; done
```

Note the backticks around `cat $file` that will execute the `cat` 'inline'.

Using `read` is another alternative. Certainly more easy to read and understand than changing the [IFS](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-IFS-154) (Internal Field Separator)

Answer (score 2):

```
while read WEBSITE PORT IP
do 
    echo $WEBSITE $IP $PORT ; 
done < file
```

But you won't be able to use this variables after the cycle has finished.